# how to get datas using id taken from url searchparam

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i work on a project with two pages. one main (index) and one "photographers".
no problem to display the datas on the main page. on the photographer page, i want to get the datas (contains in json) specific to an id which appears in the url.
i can get the id but i am unable to get the datas from json file specific to the id.
i want to diplay on this page the datas (name, location, picture) of the photographer who was targeted on the main page.
which method and how can i select and get the datas which only belongs to an id from json file?
thank you for your help.

[image: 1]

i can retrieve and get the id with searchparam but i cannot get the datas (location, picture, name, videos) from json which belongs to the specific id.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ok, sorry for that.